# How to have an alias of URL on Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, werkzeug

I'm using Flask 0.8.

How to have an alias of a URL like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # I want to display as http://localhost/index, BUT, I DON'T WANT TO REDIRECT.
    # KEEP URL with only '/'

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # Real processing to display /index view
```

So, why my hope to use an alias because of DRY of processing /index

Someone knew the solution?

thanks pepperists.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work. But why do you want two URL's to display the same thing?

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    ...
```

Comment: Potential use: API rename with partly deprecated old name.

Answer (score 9):

As is written in [URL registry doc of Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations) :

> You can also define multiple rules for the same function. They have to
>   be unique however.

```
@app.route('/users/', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>')
def show_users(page):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Flask has a way to assign more than one URL to a view function, but you could certainly chain them like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return index()

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # Real processing to display /index view
```